# Infite scrolling: Debounce or throttle?

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I'm going to make a simple infinite scrolling feature that detects the scroll position is at or near the bottom and makes a call to the server to grab more data and append it to the DOM.
I *believe* throttle makes more sense because I want that very first instance to fire when at the bottom of the page and ignore the subsequent ones but have read about people using debounce for it so I'm not sure if my thinking is incorrect now.

Comment: Neither actually. You don't want to have it timer-based, you want to wait for the previous event having loaded its data.

Answer (score 1):

why would you throttle or debounce? The request should be fired once and wait for its response. It should only trigger once the previous response was successful and the user scrolls to the next last item.

Debouncing and throttling always have a lot of drawbacks and lead to a non consistent user experience and that's what you should be caring about

In the article I wrote [here](https://dioxmio.medium.com/infinite-scroll-done-the-right-way-33cb7be18407) I put together a very sample example on how to use infinite scrolling efficiently

Comment: The article seems to not be available anymore